# Transparency issue in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

Alright, so I am having an issue with Transparency in LWJGL. It seems that the shader is not even using the alpha channel. For example, if I set the alpha channel to 0.1, everything still appears solid. However, the program I am creating only requires the object to be solid or completely clear. Normally, I would use the discard command in the fragment shader, however, I am rendering to multiple targets, so that would discard the fragment of both of the targets I am rendering to. I am also following the tutorials of ThnMatrix.

So my question is, why isn't the alpha working when rendering in my shader? I have already tried all of the GL_BLEND stuff and still no luck. Thank you!

P.S. I have another shader that renders the GUI and transparency / translucency works fine on that. The only main difference I see between the shaders is the vertex shader.

Fragment Shader:

```
 #version 330 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector[4]; 
in vec3 toCameraVector;
in float visibility;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 out_Color;
layout (location = 1)out vec4 out_BrightColour;


uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform vec3 lightColor[4];

uniform vec3 attenuation[4];

uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;

uniform float selected;


//effects 
uniform float bloomFactor = 0;



uniform vec3 skyColor;

void main(void){


vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);

vec3 totalDiffuse = vec3(0.0);
vec3 totalSpecular = vec3(0.0);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
float distance = length(toLightVector[i]);
float attFactor = attenuation[i].x + (attenuation[i].y * distance) + (attenuation[i].z * distance * distance);
vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector[i]);
float nDot1 = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
float brightness = max(nDot1, 0.0);
vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection, unitNormal);
float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection, unitVectorToCamera);
specularFactor = max(specularFactor, 0.0);
float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor, shineDamper);
totalDiffuse = totalDiffuse + (brightness * lightColor[i])/attFactor;
totalSpecular = totalSpecular + (dampedFactor * lightColor[i] * reflectivity)/attFactor;
}
totalDiffuse = max(totalDiffuse, 0.2);
vec4 textureColor = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);






out_Color = vec4(totalDiffuse, 1.0) * textureColor + vec4(totalSpecular, 1.0);
out_Color = mix(vec4(skyColor, 1.0), out_Color, visibility);
if(selected > 0.5){
out_Color.r += 0.75;

}
if(out_Color.a<0.5){
discard;

}


//float brightness = (out_Color.r * 0.2126) + (out_Color.g * 0.7152) + (out_Color.b * 0.0722);
out_BrightColour = vec4(0.0);




}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> out_Color = vec4(totalDiffuse, 1.0) * textureColor + vec4(totalSpecular, 1.0);
> ```

This equation *guarantees* that the `out_Color.a` will always be >= 1.0.

If `textureColor.a` was 0.0, completely transparent, then multiplying 0 by 1 will leave zero. Now, what happens to 0 when we add 1 to it? And that's in the case where `textureColor.a` was its lowest possible value. If it were 1.0, we'd get an `out_Color.a` of 2.0 (which will be clamped back to 1.0).

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think to look at that! However, I am still experiencing the same issue.